# Visual Studio Installation Error(s)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I get a very odd installation error, and VS Studio support couldn't fix it, so I decided to come here. I get this when installing v12, v13 and v15.
Basically, in VS15, the Visual Studio splash screen pops up, then the installation crashes.

I've got the log in a pastebin, since it'll just spam up the question.
http://pastebin.com/TXNgr7kR

The folks at VS told me it was some kind of registry key error, and that they didn't know what causes it, etc.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: "I get this when installing v12, v13 and v15".  Do you mean when you try to have all three installed at once, or that you get the exact same error regardless of the version you try to install?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I get  this whenever I try to install one them...

Comment: @Frank, you can install VS 2013 and 2015 on the same machine without problem (I've done it a few times). MS even specifically supports it: "You can install this version of Visual Studio on a computer that already has an earlier version installed." with the caveat "We recommend that you install Visual Studio versions in the order in which they were released. For example, install Visual Studio 2013 before you install Visual Studio 2015." from [Installing Visual Studio Versions Side-by-Side](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246609.aspx)

Comment: @Arraying Aside from calling VS' support, what exactly have you attempted already to fix it, and what were the results?

Comment: It looks like you have corruption in the DCOM entries for the "Task Bar Communication" object.  It could _just_ be permissions (check via `dcomcnfg`), but honestly DCOM errors like this are such a huge PITA to fix, that reinstalling Windows and your software fresh from scratch is probably your fastest/best method to get this fixed.

Comment: I can confirm you can have **ALL** versions of Visual Studio installed at the sametime.

Comment: @Ramhound I have tried installing VS 15, when that failed I tried '13, then 12.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I have not tried anything yet.

Comment: @Arraying - I have not literally tried every combination, in the past I have had VS12, VS13, and VS215 installed.  Before that I had VS05, VS08, and VS10 installed on the same system.